# Create a 'timeline' with multiple tables (SQL)

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a timeline of action that the user did (when I use his email address).

### Example:

- Subscribe to the newsletter (16/12 09h00)
- Open the newsletter (16/12 10h22)
- Click on a link (16/12 10h34)
- Click on a link (16/12 10h37)

I've **3 tables** I want to use in my timeline:

- landing (landing_email, landing_date)
- tracker (tracker_email, tracker_date)
- links (links_email, links_date)

So, the only common point is the email address (and the column has a different name in each table).

I've tried a lot of solutions but they didn't work with my case.

Comment: Please be more specific. What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: Seems like a simple UNION would suffice.

Comment: I want a list of actions and dates.
Yep UNION but I don't know how to use it in my case

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: It's ok @a_horse_with_no_name :) David Isla give me the solution thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a UNION like:

```
SELECT Email, DateTime FROM
  (SELECT landing_email as Email, landing_date as DateTime FROM landing 
   UNION 
   SELECT tracker_email as Email, tracker_date as DateTime FROM tracker
   UNION
   SELECT links_email as Email, links_date as DateTime FROM links)
WHERE EMAIL='user@domain.com'
ORDER BY DateTime;
```

Comment: Thanks !
Error: Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Edit: It's ok with a 'as "hello"' at the end (before the last WHERE):

`SELECT Email, DateTime FROM
  (SELECT landing_email as Email, landing_date as DateTime FROM landing 
   UNION 
   SELECT tracker_email as Email, tracker_date as DateTime FROM tracker
   UNION
   SELECT links_email as Email, links_date as DateTime FROM links) as timeline
WHERE EMAIL='user@domain.com'
ORDER BY DateTime;`

Thanks mate !

Comment: @JulienYatooMoors you got it! ;)